# A 1-1 continuous function from a compact space A into a Hausdorff space B

Tags: compactness

I am following a proof for the theorem:

Let g be a 1-1 continuous function from a compact space $A$ into a Hausdorff space $B$. Then $A$ and $g[A]$ are homeomorphic.

Proof:Clearly $g:A \rightarrow g[A]$ is onto, and given that $g$ is 1-1 and continuous, so $g^{-1} : g[A] \rightarrow A$ exists.It must be shown that $g^{-1}$ is continuous.$g^{-1}$ is continuous if for every closed subset of $F$ of $A$, $(g^{-1})^{-1}[F] = g[F]$ is a closed subset of $g[A]$. Now, the closed subset $F$ of a compact space $A$ is also compact. *Since $g$ is continuous, $g[F]$ is a compact subset of $g[A]$.*

I did not understand the last sentence. How it will be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$g$ is a continuous map...and the image of a compact set is compact under such maps.